# getting error ->Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
require_once 'swiftmailer/swift_required.php';
require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
function pdf_create($html,$filename,$stream = TRUE){
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('puja.pdf', $output);
}
$tym = date('g:i s');
$filename = 'print'.$tym;
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html = file_get_contents('vamshi.php');
pdf_create($html,$filename);
?>
<?php 


               // Create the mail transport configuration
                $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com',465,'ssl')
                ->setUsername('rajeshchintu.14@gmail.com')
                ->setPassword('9397343655');


               // Create the message
               $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
               ->setTo(array('saivamshigupta@gmail.com' =>'vamshi'))
               ->setSubject("Registration Success !")
               ->setBody("You have Registered Successfully ! Thank You For Registering With Us.Click link to confirm your account",'text/html')
               ->setFrom("rajeshchintu.14@gmail.com", "Rajesh")
               ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/full/file/path/puja.pdf'));
               // Send the email
               $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
               $mailer->send($message);

        if($mailer){
            echo 'eafbaefdbaifhefj';
            }
?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with
>   message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message
>   "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 g74sm5822247pfj.1 - gsmtp
>   "' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLab\new\swiftmailer\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:382
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLab\new\swiftmailer\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(279):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('535-5.7.8
>   Usern...', Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLab\new\swiftmailer\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php(243):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('RSET\r\n',
>   Array, Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLab\new\swiftmailer\classes\Swift\Transport\Esmtp\Auth\XOAuth2Authenticator.php(54):
>   Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('RSET\r\n', Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLab\new\swiftmailer\classes\Swift\Transport\Esmtp\AuthHandler.php(177):
>   Swift_Transport_Esmtp_A in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLab\new\swiftmailer\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php
>   on line 382

Answer (score 0):

Google introduced a new security feature that prevents sending of emails from less secure application. In this regard any application to developed by google is more or less considered a less secure app.

**So what does this mean for me ?**

To get around this issue you can set your google account to allow sending of emails for a less secure application.

You can do this from here https://myaccount.google.com/security

alternatively you can use another smtp server to send out your emails

here is a similar question i answered based on yii2 framework 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35908151/2536812